# Single line autogrow TextInput in react native

Tags: react-native

In React Native, if I set `multiline= true` for `TextInput`, then `enter` key will not trigger submit. It creates another line. If I set `multiline= false`, then `TextInput` does not autofit its size according to the content.

Is there a way to achieve both?

1. autofit `TextInput` size according to its text content
2. when enter is press, submit instead of adding a new line.

This is needed for [multiline chat input](https://github.com/status-im/status-react/pull/575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late to the party but...
You are looking for the [blurOnSubmit property](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#bluronsubmit):

```
<TextInput
  multiline={true} //multiline
  blurOnSubmit={true} //do not add space, call the onSubmit function
  ...
/>
```

Comment: I didn't verify it with codes because I don't do React Native much any more. But from the link to the official document, this looks like the right answer. So I'm accepting it.